# Catalan numbers with restrictions

Tags: combinations

The number of valid parenthesis expressions that consist of $n$ right parentheses and $n$ left parentheses is equal to the $n^\text{th}$ Catalan number. If we restrict that in every point，the sum of right parentheses - the sum of left parentheses is less than k. How many the valid parenthesis expressions?

Comment: What does nn mean here?

Comment: Sorry,I have edited it,it means it has n right parentheses.for example $(())())$,there are 3 right parentheses and 3 left.

Comment: Do you still keep that number of parens (left plus right) totals to $2n$? Also are you interested in the more symmetric restriction $|R=L|<k,$ with $R$ right and $L$ left parens? [or replace $<$ by $\le$]?

Comment: Yes,for example n=6, k=3,Then ()()()() is valid,but ((())) is invalid,because in the first 3 bracketis, they are all left,so the sum of left minus the sum of right is equal to 3 (3>=3),so this expression is invalid.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A080936 .